# What are the different symbols in the Witcher TV series intro?

Tags: the-witcher

In the ***The Witcher***  series of Netflix at the starting of every episode there is a symbol. What do these symbols represent? Do they have anything to do with the books?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The symbols appearing in the title card of each episode are (spoiler filled) hints towards the plot of each episode, though you will probably need to be familiar with the books to realise what they imply:

| Episode | Symbol | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. The End's Begining | Solar Eclipse | The Black Sun under which Renfri was born. |
| 2. Four Marks | The obsidian star surrounded by eels. | Yennefer (symbol of her pendent) and the other novitiates (as "conduits for Aretuza"). |
| 3. Betrayer Moon | A clawed footprint incorporating the Temerian lily. | The [shtriga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtriga), daughter of Princess Adda of Temeria. |
| 4. Of Banquets, Bastards and Burials | A broken sword surrounded by a tree. | The tree from Ciri's dream, the Sword of Destiny? |
| 5. Bottled Appetites | A female and male figure entwined, overlaying a stylised amphora. | Yennifer and Geralt; the uterine/amphora symbol painted on Yennifer's abdomen. |
| 6. Rare Species | A dragon. | Adaptation of [The Bounds of Reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sword_of_Destiny). |
| 7. Before a Fall | A shattered lion. | Symbolic of [Cintra's](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Cintra) fall (Cintra's coat of arms is three golden lions on azure). |
| 8. Much More | Gwynbleidd ("The White Wolf"), Zireael ("Swallow"), The Obsidian Star | Geralt, Ciri, and Yennefer respectively. As the previous symbols entwine to form this one, so the paths trodden by our protagonists in those episodes lead them to eachother. |

Comment: I first thought the star on the episode 8 symbol was the sun of Nilfgaard, but your version might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

## They represent people.

Do they have anything to do with the books? Yes, as you can see it's hard to decipher them without knowledge from the books.

To not spoil the series for others, the last picture is:

- **Wolf:** Geralt
- **Star:** Yennefer (she had an obsidian star pendent, but was recognized by it)
- **Swallow:** Ciri (when she was young one of her nickname was Swallow and she later named her sword that way)

Comment: Actually elven version of her name (Zireael) means swallow.

Comment: You can mention the name of the characters and enclose them in spoiler tag so that who don't want to read may ignore

Comment: which person is represented in the image of the  tree and sword